# Angular 2 initialize variable type properties

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a model with several properties, I want to initialize all the properties with a default value of empty or null.

My Model:

```
export class MyModel {
    name: string;
    jerseyNumber: number;
    etc...
}
```

Component:

```
public myObject: MyModel = new MyModel();
```

If I console.log myForm on initialization, it logs `MyForm {}`:

But what I want is for each property in myForm to be initialized with some default value, instead of being an empty object, I know I can do this manually, e.g:

```
myObject.name = null;
myObject.jerseyNumber = null;
```

But I was wondering if there is some programmatic way to do this, as MyModel has many properties, initializing each field manually seems inefficient.

Is there a way to initialize all the property values for a variable of `MyModel` type?

Thank you very much

Comment: try `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(myObject).forEach(prop => { myObject[prop] = null; })`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @ic3b3rg , unfortunately the result is still ```MyForm {} ``` after trying this. I'm not sure why when I do ```myObject: MyModel = new MyModel()``` it doesn't initialize with properties. If I log prop as in your suggestion, it has no properties

Comment: ah, I think you'll need to add an initializer to each property, e.g. `name: string = null;`

Comment: @ic3b3rg I'll give that a try, was hoping there was another way to do it, since my actual object is pretty big, thanks a bunch!

Comment: @ic3b3rg feel free to post this as an answer so I can accept. Thanks again

Comment: You're welcome - cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first thought was to use

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(myObject).forEach(prop => { myObject[prop] = null; })
```

however, TS omits uninitialized properties in the compiled class. You'll need to initialize each property, e.g.:

```
name: string = null;
```